# Could as_view() (for class-based views) be implemented in a decorator?

Tags: python, django, django-views, decorator

Django's as_view() syntax for Class-based views has been bugging me.  Basically, I am tired of having to do a my_view = MyView.as_view() for every class-based view that I want to use (or putting as_view() in every line of every url conf I use c-based views in). I think a class decorator would be a cleaner way to implement this, and I am trying to figure out how to acheive that, for my own code and to share on django snippets, in case others are interested.  So my question is: Is there a reasonable way to implement an "as_view" decorator so that the following code would be functional?

```
@as_view(my_view)
class MyView(View):
   pass
```

which would basically be equivalent to:

```
class MyView(View):
   pass
my_view = MyView.as_view()
```

Thanks,  this is also helping me learn the advanced features (i.e. decorators) of python.

Ben

Comment: The whole `as_view` thing is to make it obvious that the classes will be instantiated once per request, so you're not tempted to store state on them. So any solution needs to keep that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach that comes to mind is to have the class decorator just `setattr` some object which will contain all the `as_views` you want defined. You could then use that in your urls.py

```
import re

class Views(object):
    """Empty object for holding as_view method"""
views = Views()

def convert_name(name):
    """convert CapWords into cap_words"""
    return name[0].lower() + re.sub(r'([A-Z])', lambda m:"_" + m.group(0).lower(), name[1:])

def as_view(views):
    """Adds decorated class-based views' as_view methods to views container"""
    def decorator(cls):
        name = convert_name(cls.__name__)
        setattr(views, name, cls.as_view)
        return cls
    return decorator
```

And then in your views.py you would use it like this:

```
from as_view_decorator import views, as_view

@as_view(views)
class MyView(View):
    ....
```

..and `MyView.as_view` would be stored on the `views` object as `views.my_view`.

You could also do something like this in your views.py:

```
from as_view_decorator impor as_view
import sys; mod = sys.modules[__name__]

@as_view(mod)
class MyView(View):
    ...
```

Which would set `my_view` as an attribute on your `views` module. You could then in your `urls.py`:

```
from app.views import my_view

urlpatterns = patterns('',    
    url(r'^$', my_view()),
)
```

I think doing `my_view = MyView.as_view` is pretty simple and readable, so I'd frankly prefer that myself.

Comment: Interesting implementation.  Played around with it. In the end I decided to agree with your last line :)